# serving static content outside of public directory in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have a folder in the root of my rails 4.1.1 project called coverage that shows all of my test coverage.  I was hoping to set up a route to get to this, but since it's not in the public folder, it doesn't work.  I have the following route defined...

```
get '/rspec', :to => redirect('/coverage/index.html')
```

Is this possible to do?  If so, how?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To do this you can use `Rack::Static` by adding this to your `config/application.rb`:

```
config.middleware.use Rack::Static, :urls => ['/coverage'], :root => Rails.root.to_s
```

Answer (score 0):

You could symlink the coverage directory into your public directory

```
ln -nfs coverage public/coverage
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I'm looking for a route solution if it's possible.

Comment: I don't think there are any pure routing solutions that will do what you want.